# Using $http request results to present in differen module in Angular

Tags: angularjs, http, get

I am asking the user to put in his details and submit his form which invokes a $http request to the server and delivers data.

```
app.service('Request',function($http,$location)
var baseUrl='/system/views/files.json';
    var method='GET';
    var details={}
    this.flightReq=function(){
        $http({
            method:method,
            url:baseUrl,
            headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            params: {'dep':'a', 'arl':'b','number':'c', 'date1':'d'},
            cache:true
        })
        .success(function(data,status){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            $location.path('/resultpresentation/example');
            details.flightDet=function(){ return data }
        })
        .error(function(data,status){
            console.log(data||"Request failed");
            console.log(status);
            $location.path('/');
        })
    };
```

As the request shows, once it has been successful the user will be redirected to a new location.
However on this result page I now seek to present the results. Therefore I have to store the results in a variable or function which I need to inject into the other module. The http request is injected to both modules, but the results should only be injected to the result module.

However, even though I inject the Service Request now and use `$scope.data=Request.flightDet;` in the controller, I am not able to present the data in the view. I can see now  it is presented in the console.  The flight results are only in the console (after success but are not accessible in the view or even controllers)

However, I do not know how to do this? I hope you can help me.

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not suggested to change the route from inside a `service`. Instead, your service should just make a `$http` call and hand over the data back to the caller. Depending on the response data from the `service` call, the `controller` must do any further action.

However, you can always save the data inside `$http.success()` to a local variable inside the `service` which is making the call. And as long as you `inject` this service into any controller, you'll be able to access this data because all the AngularJS `service`s are singletons.

Edit: Saves the data to a variable inside `Request` service to be used in any consuming `controller`.

```
app.service('RequestService',function($http,$location){
   var baseUrl='/system/views/files.json';
    var method='GET';
    var flightDetails={};
    this.flightReq=function(){
    $http({
        method:method,
        url:baseUrl,
        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        params: {'dep':'a', 'arl':'b','number':'c', 'date1':'d'},
        cache:true
    })
    .success(function(data,status){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        flightDetails = data;
    })
    .error(function(data,status){
        console.log(data||"Request failed");
        console.log(status);
    });
    };

    this.getFlightDetails = function(){
        return flightDetails;
    }
};

app.controller('testController', ['RequestService', function(requestService){
 console.log(requestService.getFlightDetails());
}]);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I see, I stored the results in the service in `details.flightDet=function(){
                return data;
            }` and defined Request as `var details={}`. I can see now that the results arrive my result page successfully or at least it is presented in the console. However, even though I inject the Service `Request` now and use `$scope.data=Request.flightDet;` I am not able to present the data in the view. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Just did the changes in the service...and did some explanations

Comment: `var details = {}` creates a private variable inside the `service`. You need to expose it out by changing it to `this.details = {}`. This will solve your problem. And please accept the answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: I know what you mean. I am pretty sure we are very close. However, when using this.details says that "details is not defined". I kind of have the feeling that my function within the success callback `details.flightDet=function(){ return data }` does not return properly and is not added to the "details" object . Furthermore webstorm also tells me that it is unused in the global scope.

Comment: Where exactly do you get `details is not defined` ? Is it when you are trying to save the data in `.success()` or is it while you are trying to access `service.details` in another controller ?

Comment: I get it,when I try to access it in another controller. It tells me it is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Given your current service configuration, in the `.success` handler you can set `Request.myVar = data` and then on another page/state, you will be able to access `Request.myVar` as long as you inject that service inside of the controller(s) that you are using on that page/state

Comment: thanks for your help. I did as you suggested. However, I still encounter problems as I explain above :/...Do you figure, what is the problem?